# Error while building CppBenchmark (https://github.com/chronoxor/CppBenchmark)

Tags: c++

gcc 4.8.5 (also tried with 7.3.1)
OS Linux (Centos OS 7)

While following the build instruction of the github page, I get the following message.

/home/dev/CppSupportingCode/CppCommon/modules/CppBenchmark/modules/HdrHistogram/src/hdr_histogram.c:344:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=pedantic]
double unit_magnitude = log((double)lowest_discernible_value) / log(2);

Comment: "ISO C90", 30 years old. Can you build with less ancient standard?

Comment: I know right, but this library is a dependency another code-base, I can bypass this, but want to know, how to compile without changing original code-base. Shout out to the original developer

Comment: No need to change the code base, only the way you build. See my answer.

Comment: Note that it's actually https://github.com/HdrHistogram you're trying to build at this point.

Comment: I'm surprised this happens though, because [that project specifies `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)` in its CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/HdrHistogram/HdrHistogram_c/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L24).

Comment: Ah, only [relatively recently](https://github.com/HdrHistogram/HdrHistogram_c/commit/04cb4a110aea00e2c995af3eaa317fe9046b944f). I suggest you ask the maintainer of CppBenchmark to update their reference to `HdrHistogram`.

Comment: ... though weirdly it's not pinned to any particular version. When did you check out the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are building according to C90 standard, 30years old, though not replaced before 1999 (thanks Asteroids With Wings).
Either you actually use an ancient compiler or a newer one and you have configured it that way. Change your building.
Since the project itself is setup to tell cmake (or via cmake the compiler) to use at least C99 (thanks again Asteroids) this is a little weird. Somehow you seem to work around that configuration. Maybe you build without using the cmake config? Use a self-created project in your favorite IDE maybe?

The background is that in ancient times a mixture of declaring/defining a variable, like `double unit_magnitude = ...` was not allowed to be mixed with code like `log((double)lowest_discernible_value) / log(2);`. Newer C standards allow that and a corresponding way of building gets the code line tolerated.

Without changing any character of the built code. Only the commandline switches, which might be in a makefile or in your project configuration.

Comment: It would be more fair to say that the choice is ~20 years old, since C90 was the newest option until 1999.

Comment: It's also not a very helpful answer in context. The project in question does set C99 mode, but only since 5 months ago, so the question is really why the OP's CppBenchmark checkout is ignoring that. TBH your answer is only really saying the same thing that the compiler is, and doesn't provide a meaningful solution...

Comment: Also your edit suggests that C90 somehow became "invalid", which is not true.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings However, the information on the project setup is not within the question. My answer matches the info in the question. And answers which only translate an error message to English have proven useful in many cases. The cases of OPs not actually reading error messages or not getting the meaning. I will nevertheles also comment on that in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The question clearly states which project is being built. Is it a [mcve]? No. But, regardless, does this answer address the OP's scenario? No, we know it doesn't really.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Thanks for the comments, I think I incorporated them.

Comment: Okay it's a bit better now.

Comment: OP has the problem which using the project correctly would prevent. It is equally clear that there must be a problem most likely in how OP does (not) use the appropriate build config. They do not give details. That is what MREs are for. Though admittedly even an honest attempt might miss to specify buidling details. That is why I now discuss them explicitly. @AsteroidsWithWings Thanks for undownvoting. I respect that you chose not to upvote. Fair is fair.

Comment: _"OP has the problem which using the project correctly would prevent."_ I disagree. They're following the published instructions, and the code _should_ set C99 mode. Something is wrong. Berating them doesn't solve that. :)

Comment: True again. There are two explanations. One is that OP does not completly or correctly follow the build instructions, which would be human and I am NOT berating them for it. Or the project contains a mistake and following it completly and as meant still exhibits the problem described by OP. I tend to assume that the simpler explanation is a mistake on OPs part. This is NOT attacking them, it simply accepts the possibility that even if OP writes and believes that they follow the instructions, an accident at that is the most likely explanation. Analysing debugging the external project would ...

Comment: ... admittedly address OPs problem better and would be a really impressive answer. Yes, I admit that my answer is based on the assumption that there is something foul in the build of OP. But please accept that this is the kind of assumption I also make with colleagues which I trust, consider competent and most of them really like. It is not meant as an attack or even disregard of OP. I do however apologise for even giving the impression. @AsteroidsWithWings